# Prove that the supremum of a set of nested square roots is 2

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification, supremum-and-infimum

How can I prove that the supremum for the following set $S$ is equal to $2$ ?

$$S=\left\{\sqrt{2},\sqrt{2\sqrt{2}},\sqrt{2\sqrt{2\sqrt{2}}},\dots\right\}$$

My way is to let $a_1$ = $\sqrt{2}$ and $a_2$= $\sqrt{2 \sqrt{2}}$. Then I will rewrite $a_n+1$ = $\sqrt{2(a_n)}$ , for all $n\in \mathbb{N}$. Assume $a_k < 2 $, then $a_k+1 = \sqrt{2(a_k)} < \sqrt{2(2)} = 2$. Since $a_1 = \sqrt{2} < 2$, then by mathematical induction , $a_n < 2$. Hence $2$ is a supremum of $S$.

I not sure whether I do this right or not . Your help is very useful for me as I am going to have exam after this !

Comment: You have proven that $2$ is an upper bound, but supremum is the best upper bound. You can prove that the sequence is increasing, since $a_{n+1}=\sqrt{2a_n}\geq a_n$. Therefore, it has a limit. The limit must satisfy $L=\sqrt{2L}$. Therefore, the limit can only be $0$ or $2$. But since the sequence increases starting from $\sqrt{2}$, the limit cannot be $0$.

Comment: So, $S=\{2^{1/2},2^{3/4},2^{7/8},\ldots\}$.

Answer (score 3):

For any $\alpha\in(\sqrt{2},2)$ we have $\alpha<\sqrt{2\alpha}<2$, hence the given sequence is increasing *and* bounded, so convergent to some limit $L\in[\sqrt{2},2]$. Such limit has to fulfill $L=\sqrt{2L}$, hence $L=2$.